# Как правильно послать запрос и получить данные?

Tags: java, android

Имеются два класса, полностью одинаковые, но с одним отличием, первый класс не выдает результат, то есть ни ошибки ни результата нет. В логе пишет что `NullPointerException`, но приложение не вылетает, а просто возвращает нулевой результат. При всем при этом если взять уже сформированную ссылку например:

`http://md5decrypt.net/en/Api/api.php?hash=5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99&hash_type=md5&email=ser47400@gmail.com&code=68fdce9898fb7239`

То результат выдает корректно и без ошибок. В связи с этим вопрос в чем моя ошибка?

P. S. не претендую на лучший синтаксис, приложение просто для теста.

Первый класс

```
class Connection extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {


        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        String result_hash = "";

        String hash = editText.getText().toString();
        String link = "&hash_type=md5&email=ser47400@gmail.com&code=68fdce9898fb7239";
        String all = hash + link;


        try {

            URL url = new URL("http://md5decrypt.net/en/Api/api.php?hash=" + all);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
            result_hash = reader.readLine();


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result_hash;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        editText.setText(result);
    }
}

class DescRypted extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        String result_hash = "";

        String hash = editText.getText().toString();
        String link = "&hash_type=md5&email=ser47400@gmail.com&code=68fdce9898fb7239";
        String all = hash + link;


        try {

            URL url = new URL("http://md5decrypt.net/en/Api/api.php?word=" + all);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
            result_hash = reader.readLine();

            String LOG_TAG = "result";
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, result_hash);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result_hash;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        editText.setText(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: В одном классе `api.php?hash="` в другом `api.php?word="`. Не полностью выходит одинаковые.

Comment: Приложение не падает потому что `NullPointerException` у Вас перехватывает блок `catch`. Смотрите на какую строку указывает и разбирайтесь почему там `null`

Comment: @TimurVI какая разница данные возвращаются строковые и там и там